# Return location of everything except a substring in Rstudio

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm looking to get the location of each section of a substring defined by being the negation of a substring. I can successfully extract the substring and it's location, but not the location of everything but the substring. I tried putting the substring in [] but it gave me each character that wasn't in the string instead of evaluating it as a substring.

```
a <- "10 bananas select green apples from fruit where (select pears from apples order by fruit)"

#I can successfully extract the substrings using the following code and get the location, but I'm looking for the opposite: 
str_extract_all(a, "select.*?from")
str__locate_all(a, "select.*?from")

str_locate_all(a, "[select.*?from]")

#expected output
a<-"10 bananas" "fruit where (" "apples order by fruit)"

start end
1      10
34    47
...
```

Comment: my friend... I don't understand nothing :) Please rephrase your question

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit` from `base R` if the intention is to get separate substring

```
trimws(strsplit(a, "select.*?from")[[1]])
#[1] "10 bananas"             "fruit where ("          "apples order by fruit)"
```

Comment: That's halfway. Now, how do I get the locations of the results of strsplit?

Comment: @Aimers513 You can get the locations directly with `str_locate_all`, not clear why you need it when the main objective is to substring

Comment: I need both the extracted output as well as the location. This is part of a large project where I need both. How do I use str_locate_all with the result from trimws(strsplit(a, "select.*?from")[[1]])?